# "Result of '&&' unused" warning in a do/try/catch block

Tags: swift

I've been trying to figure out what is going on to no avail. I've distilled the code as much as possible but I still get the "Result of operator && is unused warning (even though it is used) if I do it in a project but the same code copied to Playground is working fine with no warnings. This is just some dummy code, after me rewriting the basic code again while trying to find the problem.

[image]

```
enum WordError: Error {
    case tooShort
    case tooLong
}


func isTooShort(_ word: String) throws -> Bool {
    if word.count < 3 { throw WordError.tooShort }
    return true }

func isTooLong(_ word: String) throws -> Bool {
    if word.count > 5 { throw WordError.tooLong }
    return true }


func check(_ word: String) {

    do {
        try isTooShort(word) && isTooLong(word)
        print(word)
    } catch let error as WordError {
        print("\(error)")
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

I figured I can silence the warning if I use:

```
 try _ = isTooShort(word) && isTooLong(word)
```

But I'm not sure whether that's the right way of 'patching' it.

Comment: The Playgrounds difference is not important. Playgrounds is designed to let you ignore return values since they generally show up in the right-hand gutter.

Comment: @RobNapier Oh, I see. I updated the title to remove the reference to playgrounds.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with doing it that way. The "right" way, when something like `isTooShort` belongs to you and you want to call it without capturing the result, is to mark it with `@discardableResult`. If you did that, then you could write

```
do {
    try isTooShort(word)
    try isTooLong(word)
    print(word) // if we get here, it's neither too short nor too long
} catch ...
```

But what you're doing is also "right" in these circumstances.

The *real* question is why you would both return a Bool *and* throw an error. Your implementation of `isTooShort` is very odd. You seem to be misusing `throw`. It isn't clear what problem you are trying to solve by implementing it in this odd way. `isTooShort` can only fail one way: the word is too short. So why doesn't it just return a Bool? `isTooShort` asks a simple yes/no question, so just answer it: return a Bool and stop.

If your goal is to answer a *three*-way question - i.e., to tell the caller whether this word was too short, too long, or just right, then again, just return a custom enum that answers the question:

```
enum WordLength {
    case tooShort
    case tooLong
    case justRight
}

func howIs(_ word: String) -> WordLength {
    if word.count < 3 { return .tooShort }
    if word.count > 5 { return .tooLong }
    return .justRight
}
```

Comment: In general, my advice when coding is: don't use trickery, say what you mean. If what you mean to do is tell the caller whether this word was okay and, if not, what was wrong with it, then tell the caller that. Don't play funny bool-and-throw games.

Comment: My code originally had multiple guards like:  `guard isTooShort(word) else { return showError(.tooShort) }` but I was told to change it to do/catch/throws because it wasn't the correct way of error handling. My `isTooShort` was supposed to return the bool to proceed with the checks or throw an error which would trigger an alert. I really like you three-way solution you suggested though in my actual code it would be 5-way: 4 wrong ones and 1 correct.

Comment: Excellent, that's an even stronger case for a five-way return value. — The point that I'm making is: if a function is intended to answer a question, just answer it. If a function is intended to _do_ something or _make_ something, then you might throw an error _as a side effect_ when there is invalid input. But if the question is "is my input valid and if not, why not", then just answer the question. There is _no_ error: how can there be an error when all you did was ask a question?

Comment: For example you might have a method `howIs` that returns a five-way enum telling about the word, along with a validation check that checks whether this _is_ a word, e.g. there is not supposed to be a space in it. _Then_ you could throw an error because the input is invalid. But in _your_ situation the input is _always_ valid; you are asking a valid question about valid input. So there is absolutely no reason to throw, and if someone tells you to do that, they are wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a moment but I do get it now. I'm implementing your `howIs` method now.